# How to check if dll is signed by Microsoft in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, code-signing

I want to check whether a dll or exe is signed by Microsoft Corporation. How can I check this in C# without loading the dll?

This is what I use to check the signed assembly info.

```
X509Certificate2 signedassembly = null;
try
{
    signedassembly = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(dll));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Logger.Info($"Potential Hack: {dll} is not verified!. Aborting.");
    return false;
}
```

But for Microsoft dll this is always returns null.

any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: @MickyD: I am asking about how to read the digital signature of an assembly?

Comment: @MickyD: I am talking about code signing

Comment: thanks.  I have edited your post. Wishing you well +1

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377163(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `signedassembly.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName,false); signedassembly.Verify();` Assuming that the assembly is actually signed .

Comment: @Jimi: will this make sure dll is signed by Microsoft only?

Comment: `GetNameInfo()` lets you know that the Subject/Issuer is "Microsoft Corporation", the [.Verify() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148450(v=vs.110).aspx) will validate it (using a  X509Chain). Take a look at the Remarks section to setup a logic to verify/protect against chaining engine overrides. The info in the link Hans provided, will give you more than a clue.